# If 1st XML is empty then load a different one

Tags: php, xml

Im getting the contents of an xml feed and printing the titles on my web page with php:

```
                $url = 'http://site.com/feed';
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

                foreach($xml->ART as $ART) {
                    echo $ART->TITLE;
                }
```

I want to be able to set a backup, so if the first xml isn't found a different one is loaded instead.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work. If the feed isnt found the page shows 'XML Parsing Error:' which i guess isnt the same as nothing.

```
                if ($url != '') {
                    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
                } else {
                    //Here I would load a different xml file. 
                }
```

What should I do? Should I write conditional php to check if the first url contains a TITLE, and if not load the 2nd url?

Thanks

UPDATE
This messed up my whole page:

```
                $first_url = 'http://site.com/feed1';
                $second_url = 'http://site.com/feed2';


                // if URL wrappers is enabled
                if (is_url($first_url))
                {
                  // parse first url
                  $xml = simplexml_load_file($first_url);
                }
                else
                {
                  // parse second url
                  $xml = simplexml_load_file($second_url);
                }


                foreach($xml->ART as $ART) {
                    echo $ART->TITLE;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think ive got it working with:

```
                $url = 'site.com/feed1';
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

                if ($xml == null) {
                    $url = 'site.com/feed2';
                    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
                    }

                foreach($xml->ART as $ART) {
                    echo $ART->TITLE;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [simplexml_load_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

> Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document. On errors, it will return FALSE.

Example from php.net

```
<?php
 // The file test.xml contains an XML document with a root element
 // and at least an element /[root]/title.

  if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    print_r($xml);
  } else {
     exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
  }
?>
```

EDIT: you can do

```
$url = 'http://site.com/feed';
            if( $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) ) {

                 foreach($xml->ART as $ART) {
                      echo $ART->TITLE;
                  }
            } else {
              //parsing new url
            }
```

Comment: The first code always acts like the xml is empty. Do you need the file extension? If I add .xml to the url the page isnt found.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse_xml($url)
{
  // your code
}

try
{
  parse_xml($first_url);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  parse_xml($second_url); 
}
```

Alternatively, you can do a check if the URL return XML before proceed to parsing :-

```
// if URL wrappers is enabled
if (is_url($first_url))
{
  // parse first url
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($first_url);
}
else
{
  // parse second url
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($second_url);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but can you explain how to use your code? The 2nd code looks easier to user. Do I need to change $first_url to something? Thanks

Comment: Updated with a better example

Comment: Ive updated my question with the code im trying but its messing up my whole page. Thanks